# how do i send post without verification using Certificate.loadPem?

Tags: ssl, twisted

i'm trying to send post request to daemon which is SSL applied. i want to pass the SSL verification and encrypt with SSL at the same time and here is what i found :

- verify=false

but i can't find simillar one in twisted agent.request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control TLS behavior using the `contextFactory` argument to `twisted.web.client.Agent.__init__`.

The value for this parameter should provide `twisted.web.iweb.IPolicyForHTTPS`.  This interface defines a method (`creatorForNetloc`) which is used to set up the TLS connection.

Twisted includes one distinct implementation of this interface which implements a policy like that used by most modern web browsers.

You can create your own implementation which does something else, such as disregard certificate validation errors - even on a per-host basis - or does things like adds custom trust roots so you can still verify the certificate without requiring it be issued by a certificate authority.

`twisted.internet.ssl.optionsForClientTLS` is useful for implementing some behaviors in `creatorForNetloc` - however it does not support completely ignoring all validation errors.  For that, you might benefit from using `twisted.internet.ssl.ClientTLSOptions` which accepts an arbitrary `OpenSSL.SSL.Context` instance that controls most of its behavior.

`OpenSSL.SSL.Context` lets you control approximately every feature of OpenSSL that it is possible to control when using TLS with Twisted - including ignoring validation errors, if that's what you really need.

The most straightforward way to do that is to use `Context.set_verify` with a suitably defined function.